# Append additional event data for RSS in plone

Tags: rss, plone

I'd like to customize the rss feed in plone, and append information about the location, contact person, email address and phone number of an event.
Modifying the RSS.pt template I managed to add the start date:

```
<dc:date tal:content="python: item.context.start()"></dc:date>
```

But I don't know how to access the other things (guessing like item.context.mail etc doesn't work).
Can someone give me a hint about their names, or how to find information about the context attributes and their correct names?
Using Plone4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, if you list something that is not an event, `item.context.start()` will raise an error.

You can find the schema here : https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/master/Products/ATContentTypes/content/event.py

Comment: I'll do a condition check for portal types too to prevent errors.